# Is it possible to "update data" to and "existing html template" and then "save it" as a "new html file" with vanilla JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a basic template file of which I want to update data and then "save it" as a brand new separate html file.

Is it possible to do with Vanilla JavaScript?

Here is my example code:

```js
window.onload = (event) => {

  function updateData(newData) {
    const toUpdate = document.getElementsByClassName('toUpdate')[0];
    toUpdate.innerText = 'Updated!'
  }

  updateData('Updated!')
};

// How can I save this html as a separate new html file with vanilla Javascript?
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 class="toUpdate">Not updted</h1>
</body>

</html>
<!-- How can I save this html as a separate new html file with vanilla Javascript?  -->
```

Is it possible to achieve this with Vanilla JavaScript?

Comment: Save the file where? On the server? Or on the client?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a file in memory for user to download, but not through server?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33542499)

Comment: On the server side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vanilla JavaScript (typically defied as *JavaScript + Web APIs provided by browser without third party libraries or browser extensions*) cannot save files per se.

You can:

- [Trigger a download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665115/how-to-create-a-file-in-memory-for-user-to-download-but-not-through-server) (which will typically get saved in the user's default downloads folder)
- [Make a POST or PUT request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) to a web service responsible for saving the file (on the server)
- Use the [FileSystem API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystem) to save files in a virtual sandbox